# The elements of a set are sets.

Tags: set-theory

I read some notes about set theory but I am confused. How to show that for a set $z$, its elements are sets. If I use the comprehension schema, I can say $\{x\} = \{y \in z \mid y=x\}$ is  a set but how can I show that $x$ is a set?

Comment: It rather depends on $z$.  If $z$ is the set of subsets of the natural numbers then all its elements are sets by definition; if $z$ is the set of cats in your town, then its elements are presumably not sets

Comment: $\in$(membership) in the context of ZFC is "defined" to be a binary relation between sets. So by definition any element of any set, is a set. And when I say defined, I don't mean defined in or by ZFC. I mean defined in the meta-theory as a symbol in our set theory language.

Comment: To quote D. A. Martin, 'We’re doing set theory, so “sets” are sets of sets.'

Answer (score 3):

It depends on [the set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_set_theory) you're working in:

In [ZFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory) (the standard set theory), everything is a set, so every element of $z$ must be a set.

In [NBG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory) and [MK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse%E2%80%93Kelley_set_theory), a set is a class that belongs to some class. Every element of $z$ (which is a set and therefore a class) belongs to some class (namely $z$) and is therefore a set.

In [Ackermann set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_set_theory), this follows from the transitivity axiom
$$y \in z \land z \in V \rightarrow y \in V$$
where $V$ is interpreted as "the class of all sets".